# Is a cosmopolitan totalitarian regime realistic?

Tags: government, politics, dictatorship

What I mean is I did the political test of eight values, and I saw the results of many other people. I think there is a negative correlation between being open to the world and being in favor of authority. Most totalitarian states are patriotic/nationalistic/chauvinistic (Nazi Germany, North Korea, Saudi Arabia). At the opposite, most anarchists are peaceful/internationalist/cosmopolitan. That said, the only example of a cosmopolitan totalitarian is Emperor Sheev Palpatine/Darth Sidious from *Star Wars* (property of The Walt Disney Company), and the only example of a chauvinistic anarchist is Joker from *Dark Knight Trilogy* (property of Warner Media), but they do not exist.

Comment: Does the Soviet Union (particularly the early one from 1920s) count as a "cosmopolitan totalitarian regime"?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Soviet Union was close to pan-Slavism.

Comment: [Third International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_International), better known as the Comintern. And those *peaceful* anarchists have carried out many political assassinations...

Comment: @mammifereviolet4694 What about the Romans? They were very open to new cultural experiences and the empire was culturally diverse, but were super authoritarian and saw all non-Romans as little better than barbarians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes! Just need some *very* common propaganda to link the two concepts.

Taking the definition of [Cosmopolitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmopolitanism) as:

> Cosmopolitanism is the idea that all human beings are, or could or should be, members of a single community

and [Totalitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarianism) as:

> Totalitarianism is a concept for a form of government or political system that prohibits opposition parties, restricts individual opposition to the state and its claims, and exercises an extremely high degree of control over public and private life.

These can of course co-exist with one additional doctrine; **define anyone who doesn't agree with your politics as a non-human**, or make them a non-citizen. Those who are loyal are the only humans who count, and are therefore all are members of the only community.

Alternatively:

- A democidal totalitarian regime that succeeds in murdering all opposition will become cosmopolitan logically - there are no other remaining humans not in the single community.
- Good indoctrination in schools, or just full mind control tech, could ensure there is no formation of opposition either. This would also form a single community all loyal.

Answer (score 1):

If corporations gained control of government, they could work hand in hand to dominate world markets and stifle new competition through over regulation and government imposed monopoly. In fact they could even tax people and give the money to multinational companies through subsidies and government contracts. In turn, news and social media corporations could stifle democracy by spreading propaganda and censoring anyone who calls out the corruption and rigged elections.

Now a corporation doesn't care what color your skin is or what language you speak. They just want to make as much money as possible. Unfortunately corporations also don't care about freedom or human rights if it doesn't make them money, and they'll gladly throw people in prison if it means a captive market and cheap labor.

"Fascism should more appropriately be called Corporatism because it is a merger of state and corporate power."

~Benito Mussolini